# SSRS Report Manager not showing up properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm new to Reporting Services and have started creating Reports recently. 
 I am creating reports in BIDS that comes with **MS SQL Server**, for my purpose, *R2*, and have configured the **Reporting Server** also. Everything is fine. I am able to preview the reports, debug, deploy  and all, using the BIDS.
But, the problem is, when I click the **Report Manager URL** in the **Reporting Service Configuration Manager** and expect to see the **[Report Manager as a Web application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147%28v=sql.105%29.aspx/)**, I instead, end up with a non-graphical web page, displaying the text based links to directories like this:
[image]

---

and Ultimately, I get no options like:(**as shown in MSDN**)

- Click **Site Settings** at the top of the page
- Click the **Security** tab at the side of the page etc.

Yes, of course, I did try to run the Browser as Administrator and then enter the Report Manager URL in it, yet again, I get the same screen
Any suggestions ? Would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks.

Comment: The screen shot you posted is valid, its called the "Report Server" this is essential to call the report server when passing parameters for instance.  What you want to view is the report manager, generally that can be found at `http://reportservername/reports`

Comment: @JonH Thank-you JonH, I had seen this at a lot of places, but now only when I changed the URL to "reports" in Configuration Manager, it worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screen shot you posted is valid, its called the "Report Server" this is essential to call the report server when passing parameters for instance. What you want to view is the report manager, generally that can be found at `http://reportservername/reports`

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what JonH has posted: In Reporting Services Configuration Manager - click the Report Manager URL link in the left column.  In the box next to "Virtual Directory:" Type the name you want...My company reports.  Click Apply, once the manager has completed you should be able to click the new URL and see the Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... I was facing same issue.

I installed SQL server Express 2012 version. BY Default the 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager' points to "ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS" as the Virtual Directory in "Web Service URL" & "Report Manager URL" by Default. So by Default it becomes like;

Report Server:  _http://zed:80/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS

Report Manager: _http://zed:80/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS

So the Reports Home page is not displayed.

I changed as Below, "Report" as the Virtual Directory in "Web Service URL" & "Reports" as the Virtual Directory in "Report Manager URL". So it becomes like below.

Report Server: _http://zed/report

Report Manager: _http://zed/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx